# Unicode not shown in my app when i run on jar file

Tags: java, netbeans, unicode

I build a Java GUI application and i had some `jLabel` with Unicode text. When i run the app from NetBeans IDE the text displayed as a correct form, But when i run from `.jar` file the text displayed as a deformed form.

**My code:**

```
try {
    jLabel1.setText(new String("ژمارا ناسنامی".getBytes(), "UTF-8"));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(dataEntry.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

**Output :**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this only:

```
jLabel1.setText("ژمارا ناسنامی");
```

Indeed your error here is to first encode your `String` with `getBytes()` which uses the **default encoding** and then you decode it into `UTF-8` which is incorrect as you rely on the default encoding that could not be `UTF-8` and useless as a `String` is already `UTF-16` encoded so it covers already arabic characters.

Here is the Javadoc of the method [String#getBytes()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes--) as reminder:

> Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's
>   **default charset**, storing the result into a new byte array. The
>   behavior of this method when this string cannot be encoded in the
>   default charset is unspecified. The CharsetEncoder class should be
>   used when more control over the encoding process is required.

If you want to encode properly a `String`, you need to to use [String#getBytes(Charset)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes-java.nio.charset.Charset-) or [String#getBytes(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes-java.lang.String-) instead. But once again, it is not even needed in this particular case.